# How can i set one interval for several divs?

Tags: javascript

There is example for one DIV. But now i need more bats. How can i make 1 setInterval for all bats=getElementsByClassName("bat")?

```
var bat = document.getElementByID("bat");
function batAnimation(bat) {
  var frame = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  switch (frame) {
    case 1:
      bat.style.backgroundPositionX=0;
      break;
    case 2:
      bat.style.backgroundPositionX=10;
      break;
    case 3:
      bat.style.backgroundPositionX=20;
      break;
    case 4:
      bat.style.backgroundPositionX=30;
      break;
  }
}
setInterval(batAnimation, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var bats = document.getElementsByClassName("bat");
    function batAnimation(bat) {
      var frame = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      for(var i=0; i< bats.length;i++){
        bats[i].style.backgroundPositionX=(frame-1)*10;
      }
    }
    setInterval(batAnimation, 50);
```

*Explanation:* here bats is an array of all the div elements, I am traversing it using a for loop and assigning the backgroundPositionX to each.

As getElementsByClassName doesn't work in all browers so add the function if not available

```
if(!document.getElementsByClassName){
 document.getElementsByClassName(clasName){
  var parent = document;
  var elements = parent.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var matching = [];
  for(var i = 0, elementsLength = elements.length; i < elementsLength; i++){
    if ((' ' + elements[i].className + ' ').indexOf(findClass) > -1) {
      matching.push(elements[i]);
    }
  }
  return matching;
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `for(bat in bats)` does what you think it does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in